# Auto-stack labels in stacklayout without margin

Tags: xamarin, stacklayout

I'm having problem with not being able to stack two labels in a `StackLayout` and fit the content without a margin.

**Expected result:**
[image]

**Current output:**

[image]

I have tried and set the `VerticalOptions`, `Margin` and `Padding` properties but it still contains the margin (the red background) as well as the second content is not touching the "ceiling" of it's `StackLayout` parent.

**Current code:**

```
<ViewCell>
    <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" VerticalOptions="Start">
    <StackLayout HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center">
        <Image Source="summary.png"/>
    </StackLayout>
    <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical" VerticalOptions="Start" BackgroundColor="Red" Margin="0" Padding="0">
        <StackLayout BindingContext="{Binding Date}" VerticalOptions="Start" BackgroundColor="Beige" Margin="0" Padding="0">
          <Label Text="{Binding Text}" TextColor="{Binding Color}" VerticalOptions="Start"/>
        </StackLayout>
        <StackLayout BindingContext="{Binding Result}" VerticalOptions="Start" BackgroundColor="Blue" Margin="0" Padding="0">
          <Label Text="{Binding Text}" TextColor="{Binding Color}" FontSize="{Binding FontSize}" VerticalOptions="Start"/>
        </StackLayout>    
    </StackLayout>                                
    </StackLayout>
</ViewCell>
```

Comment: I'd start by removing all the unnecessary StackLayouts you have - I see at least three that only have a single child and aren't needed

Comment: I would clean up/simplify your view as Jason mentioned. Also, StackLayouts have a default `Spacing="6"` so try setting that to 0.